# How to remove selected data that found on another list and take last 6 id through LINQ without foreach loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables `User` and `Income`. I am selecting `usersId` from `Income table` like:

```
var SelectedId= 
  objdb.Incomes.Where(x => x.NewUserId ==model.UserId).Select(x=>x.UserId).ToList();
```

now I want to select last 6 UserId from `User` that does not contain `SelectedId`
I know I can select six `UserId` like

```
objdb.Users.Select(x=> x.UserId).Take(6).ToList();
```

But I want only those `data` that doesn't in `selected ID`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Where` clause with `x => !SelectedId.Contains(x.UserId)` as the predicate.

```
objdb.Users.Where(x => !SelectedId.Contains(x.UserId))
           .Select(x=> x.UserId)
           .Take(6)
           .ToList();
```

reads as "retrieve the first 6 UserId's from `Users` where the UserId is not contained in the `SelectedId`'s and collect to a list".

If you want the last `6` based on some criteria then use `OrderByDescending`:

```
objdb.Users.Where(x => !SelectedId.Contains(x.UserId))
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.[property])
           .Select(x => x.UserId)
           .Take(6)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Also, *last* should be *last based on a criteria*, so use an `.OrderBy(x => x.[property])` or `.OrderByDescending(x => x.[property])`